# Popup.html is the same in all tabs (Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-developer-tools

My extension checks for broken images on a website. Everything works fine if I open an URL at a time but if I open several URLs from one site, the summary in popup.html is always the same as the active tab (it's not updated for each site).

I don't know how to refer to the actual URL of the analysis and avoid the "active tab". Any ideas?

**Manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Test",
"permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage","tabs"],
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Test",

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab*"],
    "exclude_globs": ["*#*"],
    "js": ["jquery-3.4.1.min.js", "content.js"]
  }
],

"web_accessible_resources": ["popup.html"],

 "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": {
    "16": "images/ico.png",
    "32": "images/ico.png",
    "48": "images/ico.png",
    "128": "images/ico.png"
  }
},
"manifest_version": 2
```

}

**Content.js**

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, response) => {
  if (msg.subject === 'DOMInfo') {      
    var domInfo = {
      images: number_images   
    };
    response(domInfo);
  }
});
```

**Popup.js**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  }, tabs => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
        tabs[0].id,
        {subject: 'DOMInfo'},
        setDOMInfo);
  });
});
```

I'm pretty sure is the `tabs[0].id` that causes the problem but I'm not sure how I can refer to the current URL that run the content.js script and make sure the popup.html gets the analysis from this URL. Any ideas?

In the background.js I had no problem referring the sender tab:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) 
{   
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, windowType:"normal", currentWindow: true},function(d){

        var tabId =  sender.tab.id;     
        ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming popup.html is loaded into an `iframe` inside the web pages by your content script, you need [chrome.tabs.getCurrent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent) that returns **the tab where this code is running** so each iframe will find its own tab:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(tab => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {subject: 'DOMInfo'}, callback);
});
```

P.S. When using `sender.tab.id` you don't need chrome.tabs.query - you already have the id.

Comment: That worked perfectly! thanks for the PS tip, you were also right ;)